# vercel can't support apollo-graphql subscription

Tags: node.js, next.js, graphql, apollo, graphql-subscriptions

I have a Next.js / Node.js project, I built it and finally I decided to upload it on Vercel, I did everything fine but the problem is that I can't use Graphql-subscription, Vercel told me that I couldn't support the subscription function, but you can use SWR instead of a subscription. I am so confused because I should move on to SWR, but I think there are ways to use subscriptions for Vercel.

but if there is no way to use subscriptions on Vercel, then please give me some advice on what I can do.

Is SWR an effective way to use as a subscription alternative?

Thank you for your attention